# What'st the problem? In target 'video_player_avfoundation' from project 'Pods'

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

Where is the problem?

I get this Error on running Testflight from iOS `in target 'video_player_avfoundation' from project 'Pods'`

```
Ld /Users/pin-chientseng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfllcubjuppngacurzilkdnplylp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/video_player_avfoundation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/video_player_avfoundation normal x86_64 (in target 'video_player_avfoundation' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/pin-chientseng/Desktop/yomate/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -L/Users/pin-chientseng/Desktop/yomate/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/video_player_avfoundation -F/Users/pin-chientseng/Desktop/yomate/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/video_player_avfoundation -F/Users/pin-chientseng/Development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator -filelist /Users/pin-chientseng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfllcubjuppngacurzilkdnplylp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/video_player_avfoundation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/video_player_avfoundation.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/video_player_avfoundation.framework/video_player_avfoundation -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/pin-chientseng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfllcubjuppngacurzilkdnplylp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/video_player_avfoundation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/video_player_avfoundation_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Flutter -framework Foundation -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/pin-chientseng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfllcubjuppngacurzilkdnplylp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/video_player_avfoundation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/video_player_avfoundation_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/pin-chientseng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bfllcubjuppngacurzilkdnplylp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/video_player_avfoundation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/video_player_avfoundation

ld: framework not found Flutter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: rm xcode then re-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rm xcode then re-install, I think this is bug